Azure AD authentication with Azure Functions sporadically has Request.IsAuthenticated flag is false
I am using React MSAL authentication with react MSAL library and Azure infrastructure: Azure functions, Azure AD/Entra.
From time to time, sporadically and mostly after the application(Azure Functions API endpoints) was non-touched/redeployed, not used for concrete time by users(for instance 7-9 hours no one tried to authenticate/authorize from client app) I receive 401 error while trying to send a request to my endpoints after authorization and IsAuthenticated is false at backend(Azure Functions), but token is presented, scope is presented, token JWT is not expired. BUT, If I refresh the page/do re-login instantly right after this error, the request sent successfully without 401 error and login is successfull of course.
Well, the hell in this issue that this is sporadically and it is really super hard to catch it manually, even if error occurred, after this error and refresh the page everything works fine until the next error(next day, pause in using of application/ redeploy).
What I have:
I have biceps to deploy Functions:
resource fa_tools_config 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: app_name_resource
  name: 'authsettingsV2'
  properties: {
    globalValidation: {
      requireAuthentication: true
      unauthenticatedClientAction: 'AllowAnonymous' 
    }
    httpSettings: {
      forwardProxy: {
        convention: 'NoProxy'
      }
      requireHttps: true
      routes: {
        apiPrefix: '/.auth'
      }
    }
    identityProviders: {
      apple: {
        enabled: false
      }
      azureActiveDirectory: {
        enabled: true
        login: {
          disableWWWAuthenticate: false
        }
        registration: {
          clientId: authClientId
          openIdIssuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/${subscription().tenantId}/v2.0/'
        }
        validation: {
          allowedAudiences: [
            authClientId
          ]
          defaultAuthorizationPolicy: {
            allowedPrincipals: {}
          }
          jwtClaimChecks: {}
        }
      }
      facebook: {
        enabled: false
      }
      gitHub: {
        enabled: false
      }
      google: {
        enabled: false
      }
      legacyMicrosoftAccount: {
        enabled: false
      }
      twitter: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
    login: {
      allowedExternalRedirectUrls: []
      cookieExpiration: {
        convention: 'FixedTime'
        timeToExpiration: '08:00:00'
      }
      nonce: {
        nonceExpirationInterval: '00:05:00'
        validateNonce: true
      }
      preserveUrlFragmentsForLogins: false
      routes: {}
      tokenStore: {
        enabled: false
        tokenRefreshExtensionHours: 72
      }
    }
    platform: {
      enabled: true
      runtimeVersion: '~1'
    }
  }
}

This is a code to check the authorization:
private static bool UserAuthenticated(
  HttpRequest request, 
  out string? errorMessage)
{
  if (Env.IsLocalDevelopment)
  {
      errorMessage = null;
      return true;
  }
  if (request.HttpContext.User.Identity is null)
  {
      errorMessage = "User identity is null. Request.HttpContext.User.Identity is null.";
      return false;
  }
  if (!request.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
      // HERE IS ERROR, Identity is presented but IsAuthenticated is false!
      errorMessage = "User identity is null. Request.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.";
      return false;
  }
  errorMessage = null;
  return true;
}

and I also has a React code:
login function:
static async login(email: string) {
  const nonce = newGuid();
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('_nonce', '' + nonce);

  const loginRequest = {
    scopes: scopeArray,
    loginHint: email,
    nonce: nonce,
  } as RedirectRequest;

  await this.msalInstance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
}

authorization code:
const msalConfig: Configuration = getMsalConfig({
  redirectUri: appConfig.getAppUrl(),
  clientId: appConfig.getClientId(),
  authority: appConfig.getTenantId(),
});

this.msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

this.msalInstance.addEventCallback(async (event: EventMessage) => {
  const payload = event.payload as any;

  if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS && payload.account) {
    const account = payload.account;
    const rolesFromJWT = this.parseRolesFromJWT(payload.idToken);

    this.msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);

    window.localStorage.setItem(JWT_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, payload.idToken);
  }

  if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGOUT_SUCCESS) {
    await this.clearAllCache();
  }
})

and my config msal:
const getMsalConfig = (props: MsalConfigProps): Configuration => ({
  auth: {
    clientId: props.clientId,
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${props.authority}`,
    redirectUri: props.redirectUri,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  }
});

export const scopeArray = ['email', 'openid', 'user.read', 'user.read.all', 'user.readbasic.all', 'profile'];

Would like to inform that I receive JWT token, it is not expired, at client app everything looks ok as well(sending the request when it is authenticated and has a jwt etc. and activeAccount field is set)
I would be grateful if you say the idea how to get to the bottom of the situation, looks like the problem at backend side/azure functions or at AD. I also check the similar topics related to IsAuthenticated field with AD, but not found. Thanks

Check if there are any discrepancies or delays in token validation or session management, possibly triggered by idle periods or token refreshes. Additionally, consider enabling detailed logging and monitoring mechanisms to capture and analyze the behavior during these intermittent failures for deeper insight
